# android Google plus login customization

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm creating a Android application and right now i'm implementing the social networks login.

Facebook button is fine, but the google+ button is in a different language of the facebook one. Also, it only says "sign in", and i would like to have it to say "sign in with google"

I'm new to the android programation, and saw that i need to make a custom button, but dont know how to do it(where to start it, how to call it) and make it look like google plus one.

Could anyone give me a little bit of help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two ways:

1) Fight it with a custom button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGooglePlus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_dark"
    android:text="@string/common_signin_button_text_long"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="62dp"/>
```

2) Don't fight it (too much):

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btnGooglePlus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

mGooglePlusSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btnGooglePlus);
mGooglePlusSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
setGooglePlusTextAllCaps(mGooglePlusSignInButton, false);

public static void setGooglePlusTextAllCaps(SignInButton signInButton, boolean allCaps)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof TextView)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setAllCaps(allCaps);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The main trick seems to be the "mGooglePlusSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);" method.

Comment: when i tried to use a custom button,  the sign in fragment crashed with this error: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

Comment: What does the method 1 do with SignIn button?

Comment: It's just a normal button using the official google resources. It is up to you to handle onClick and implement the calls to actually sign in...thus why I said "1) Fight it"

Answer (score 7):

Try this function to change google plus button text.

```
protected void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton,
        String buttonText) {
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setTextSize(15);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            tv.setText(buttonText);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UNLESS YOU WANT TO YELL AT YOUR USERS YOU SHOULD PROBABLY ALSO ADD "tv.setAllCaps(false);"

Comment: Can't tell you how much this answer saved my ...!

Answer (score 3):

Set `app:buttonSize="wide"` like this

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonSize="wide"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"/>
```

But, don't forget to add this xml namespace prefix in the top

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Customizing your Google+ sign in button guide](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#customizing_your_sign-in_button), you can use

```
android:text="@string/common_signin_button_text_long"
```

to get the text 'Sign in with Google' on your sign in button as discussed in the [Google+ sign in branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines#sign-in-button)

Comment: That doesn't work on the SignInButton class, it only works on a custom Button/ImageButton. Their canned images aren't even validly named for an Android drawable resource, and it would be nice if they provided a selector drawable for the disabled/focused/pressed/normal states! :(