# Custom Google+ Sign In Button

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, customization

I want to have more control over the social login buttons in my app and that all of them look the same regarding size, margin, padding, etc.

---

For that puprose I do e.g. not use the ready built facebook login button, but a normal button with the according style from the facebook SDK:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/myFacebookButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="@string/com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        style="@style/com_facebook_button"/>
```

Right now I am trying to do the same for the google sign in button, but I can't seem to find an according style or icon drawable.

---

Is there someone who could point me to the right direction?

---

**UPDATE to clarify the question:**

What I do not know is if there is already a ready to use style and drawable inside the auth package and if yes where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no custom style for G+ button in the SDK. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/#customizing_your_sign-in_button
Take a look at this answer if in case you are looking for customizing it on your own. -https://stackoverflow.com/a/29658836/6715557

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnGooglePlus"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_dark"
android:text="@string/common_signin_button_text_long"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textAllCaps="false"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:paddingStart="62dp"/>
```

or,

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
android:id="@+id/btnGooglePlus"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
mGooglePlusSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btnGooglePlus);
mGooglePlusSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
setGooglePlusTextAllCaps(mGooglePlusSignInButton, false);

public static void setGooglePlusTextAllCaps(SignInButton signInButton,boolean allCaps)              
{
for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

    if (v instanceof TextView)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        tv.setAllCaps(allCaps);
        return;
    }
 }
}
```

You can make your own drawable or simply download it from the internet.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I was not clear enough in my question. I know how to implement a custom button. What I do not know is if there is already a ready to use style and drawable inside the auth package and if yes where to find it.